# What is responsible for making the bonds identical?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

Here is an MO diagram of methane found on the internet:

[image]

There are 4 bonds here, one involving the 2s of carbon, three involving the 2p of carbon, and they have different energies.

However, I am told that the four bonds are actually equal.

Then what made them equal? Also, I am told that hybridisation does not exist.

Comment: Re: "I am told that hybridisation does not exist." Think of the Kekulé structure for benzene. Benzene doesn't "vibrate" between the two double bond models. Bonding using Molecular Orbit Theory shows that benzene is really aromatic. So MOT is a both a more sophisticated and more realistic model for bonding, but it is more complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hydrogens are all equivalent. When thinking about MOT, you have to throw almost everything you thought you knew about bonding out the window. The electrons are not localized between any two pair of atoms—they are truly **molecular** orbitals. This graphic nicely shows the phasing of the molecular orbitals of methane:

$\hspace{4cm}$[image: methane MOs]

[[source](http://www.lasalle.edu/~prushan/IC-articles/Polyatomic%20Molecular%20Orbital%20Theory.pdf)]

The lowest energy orbital is a linear addition of the carbon $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital and all four of the hydrogen $\mathrm{1s}$ orbitals. The pair of electrons occupying this orbital is not specific to any one hydrogen, and bonds all the atoms in methane together (even the hydrogens to the other hydrogens). The other bonding orbitals are of degenerate energy and result from linear combinations of the carbon $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals and the hydrogen $\mathrm{1s}$ orbitals.

Naturally a molecular orbital that results from a combination of a $\mathrm{s}$ orbital will be of lower energy than one than one that results from a $\mathrm{p}$ orbital.

Comment: May I ask which software you used to draw the diagram?

Comment: Also, how did you obtain the energies?

Comment: I like your explanation. A simple rule taught which may be too simple is that a lower energy MO is a stronger bond and these are (geometrically) shorter...why doesn't the MO theory match the geometry of the shape? or am I overlooking something in your explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is that the bond lengths  between any two types of atoms in a molecule will be the same if exactly the same forces forming the bond act on each atom, i.e. those resulting from electrostatic interaction between electrons and nuclei. 
Thus, in a molecule such a methane we expect all C-H bonds to be the same length, as there are only one type of  C-H bonds, in other molecules we expect each C-C, C=C, or S=O bond etc.  to be the same as others of the same type, unless other nearby atoms perturb them causing a change in electrostatic interactions and so bond length. 
We know by experiment that the typical, or average, values for CC single, double or triple bonds are approx 154, 134 & 120 pm respectively (& approx 140 pm in aromatics), but actual values differ very slightly between different types of molecules as can be observed by x-ray crystallography, or for small molecules, microwave spectroscopy in the vapour phase.

A conventional molecular formula can be misleading, for example, in $\ce{HNO3}$  one NO bond has a different length to the two others because the structure is $\ce{HONO2}$ and so one oxygen is bound as H-O-N, the other two as N=O. There are clearly many other examples such as this.

In the case of methane, and numerous other molecules such as $\ce{H2Be, H2O, NH3 SO2 NO3- }$, benzene  etc., bonds are the  same length because there are only two types of atoms present and the molecules have some symmetry. However, there are very important exceptions, e.g. $\ce{[CoF6]^{3-}}$  where there are also only two types of atoms. Unequal bond lengths occurs in many other complexes with one type of ligand, such as $\ce{[Cu(H_2O_6)]^{2+}}$, where the degeneracy of an electronic state plays a role in stabilising the energy by what is called the Jahn-Teller Effect. Organic molecules such as cyclobutadiene ($\ce{C4H4}$) also show JT distortions.

The Jahn-Teller theorem states that any non-linear molecule in a degenerate electronic state (orbit or spin) will be unstable and by distortion will lower its symmetry and split the degeneracy. It does not state what the distortion will be, i.e. how the molecule’s geometry will change or how big this change will be, just that it will occur and have the effect of lowering symmetry and energy. (It also states that if there is a centre of inversion this will be maintained). The figure shows, in a very schematic way (as energy gaps are not to scale), what happens to d orbital energy levels for an octahedral $\ce{ d^9 Cu^{2+} }$ complex.

[image: JT-octahedron]

Note that the average orbital energy remains the same after applying the JT interaction (right), the doubly degenerate $e_g$ levels rise and fall equally, and with the triply degenerate $t_{2g}$ levels, two levels fall by 1/3 of the splitting, the other rises by 2/3.

As can be seen in the $\ce{ d^9 }$ complex there is no stabilisation of the $t_{2g}$ levels as they are all filled, but there is a stabilising energy of the $e_g$ by $\delta _e/2$ and this is achieved by lengthening two opposite bonds in this octahedral complex. The two axial ligands are approx 238 pm long and the four equatorial ones (those in a square plane) are approx 195 pm. 
The effect of Jahn-Teller splitting can often be observed in the visible absorption spectrum of complexes.
 In the $\ce{V^{IV} d^1 complex VCl4}$, the JT effect occurs and at *low* temperature this molecule forms a elongated tetrahedral structure.

Comment: So which interesting question are you actually answering? Not the one presented here, unfortunately.

Comment: yes actually it it is an interesting question, but so as to not to appear patronising I've removed this comment.  I answer the question generally in the first paragraph, then point out that in molecules such as the OP mentions in his question, there are cases when bond lengths can be different even though at first sight one would expect them to be the same.

Comment: Oh, I too believe this question here is interesting. However, it is specifically asking for methane, and why the bond lengths are equal while the MO diagram seems to suggest inequivalent bonds. Unfortunately, even with your edit you do not address that adequately; especially since 70 or so % of your answer deal with other compounds that don’t need to be mentioned.

Comment: The title to the question is quite general about bonds;  then asks about methane. I answer the general question as it also applies to methane; then as I say in my previous comment, I point out that its not as simple as using MO blindly as it will give the wrong answers in some cases. It seems very restrictive and possibly misleading  just to answer wrt methane when there are other molecules to which following the same treatment will produce wrong answers. I can see we probably wont agree, however.

Comment: @Jan lol calm down, i think that the idea of answering in general instead of specific is quite interesting, although s/he really didn't talk about MO diagrams.